# Update deployment via linux script in weblogic

Tags: linux, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

What is the script to update deployment ( from GUI, we can do this update by unlock & save changes ) in linux. Is it possible to do this ? If not what is script to redeploy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin pointed out, WLST is the way to go. You should probably craft a script (named `wlDeploy.py`, for instance), with content like follows (`import` clauses were omitted for the sake of simplicity):

```
current_app_name = '[your current deployed app name]'
new_app_name = '[your new app name]'
target_name = '[WL managed server name (or AdminServer)]'
connect([username],[pwd],'t3://[admin server hostname/IP address]:[PORT]')  
stopApplication(current_app_name)
undeploy(current_app_name, timeout=60000);
war_path = '[path to war file]'
deploy(appName=new_app_name, path=war_path, targets=target_name);
```

And call it via something like:

```
./wlst.sh wlDeploy.py
```

Of course you can add parameters to your script, and a lot of logic which is relevant to your deployment. This is entirely up to you. The example above, though, should help you getting started.

Answer (score 1):

In WebLogic you can use wlst to perform administrative tasks like managing deployments. If you google weblogic wlst, you will receive tons of information. wlst runs on the python language.

Assuming you are using weblogic 10 you can also "Record" your actions. This will save the actions into a python script which you can "replay" (execute) later.